# Pass data from interface in Activity to another Activity

Tags: android

I try pass value from `Fragment` to `Activity` using interface:

```
 public interface OnSelectedButtonListener {
    void onButtonSelected(int buttonIndex);
}
```

This is working, but when I try pass value from interface in `Activity` to another `Activity` I get null. How to resolve this problem in another way?

```
@Override
public void onButtonSelected(int buttonIndex) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ArticleActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("text",buttonIndex);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: why are you using interface to passing the data to the other activity send the data using intent. is there any specific reason for using interface for sending the data to activity ?

Comment: Show your code "getting the value from another Activity" resulting in `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this lesson [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

**MainActivity**

At the top of the MainActivity class, add the EXTRA_MESSAGE definition as follows:

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
```

and call the start activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ArticleActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, buttonIndex);
startActivity(intent)
```

**ArticleActivity**

Inside OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) get the intent and assign it to a local variable.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int index;
if (intent != null) {
   index = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, 0);
}
```